# How to emit sound of specified frequency for a specified amount of time?

Tags: sound

Sorry but I am confused by several sound/play commands in Mathematica. What I want to do is to emit a succession of sounds according to a succession of frequencies and durations. Specifying timbres would be even nicer. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Play` to produce a fixed-duration sound of arbitrary frequency. For example to play, to get a 2600 Hz tone for 1 second you could use:

```
Play[Sin[2600 2 π t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

To play a sequence of fixed-duration sounds , you can use `Sound` on a list of `Play` functions as shown in the first Scope example [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Play.html).

For those of a certain age, here is a sequence that might sound familiar and helpful.

```
Sound[{Play[Sin[350 2 π t] + Sin[440 2 π t], {t, 0, 1}],
  Play[Sin[770 2 π t] + Sin[1336 2 π t], {t, 0, 0.2}],
  SoundNote[None, 0.1],
  Play[Sin[770 2 π t] + Sin[1336 2 π t], {t, 0, 0.2}],
  SoundNote[None, 0.1],
  Play[Sin[770 2 π t] + Sin[1336 2 π t], {t, 0, 0.2}],
  SoundNote[None, 0.1],
  Play[Sin[697 2 π t] + Sin[1209 2 π t], {t, 0, 0.2}],
  SoundNote[None, 0.1],
  Play[Sin[697 2 π t] + Sin[1336 2 π t], {t, 0, 0.2}],
  SoundNote[None, 0.1],
  Play[Sin[697 2 π t] + Sin[1209 2 π t], {t, 0, 0.2}],
  SoundNote[None, 0.1],
  Play[Sin[697 2 π t] + Sin[1336 2 π t], {t, 0, 0.2}]}]
```

**Edited** to add 100 ms silence breaks between sounds with `SoundNote[None, 0.1]`.

*For regular use*, I would define my own functions using Map to simplify. For example:

```
freqSound[freqs_, duration_] := Play[Sum[Sin[2 \[Pi] t f], {f, Flatten[{freqs}]}], {t, 0, duration}]
freqSequence[listFreqDur___] := Sound[Map[freqSound[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, {listFreqDur}]]
```

These can be used to reproduce the sounds above like this (where I am using a 1 Hz tone as quick shorthand for an inaudible silence):

```
freqSound[{350, 440}, 1]
freqSequence[{{350, 440}, 1}, {{770, 1336}, 0.2}, {1, 0.1}, {{770, 1336}, 0.2}, {1, 0.1}, {{770, 1336}, 0.2}, {1, 0.1}, {{697, 1209}, 0.2}, {1, 0.1}, {{697, 1336}, 0.2}, {1, 0.1}, {{697, 1209}, 0.2}, {1, 0.1}, {{697, 1336}, 0.2}]
```

Comment: Sorry it sounds [quite strange](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz5n7ThWFJHONWxGR2J4UlJPTEk) on my computer, I cannot recognize any melody, what is it supposed to be? Does it depend on hardware?

Comment: Aha now I've got it :D

Comment: Looks like I should accept that. Seems however strange that there is no simpler command to do that

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, I would just construct my own helper functions using Map based on the specific sounds and input syntax I would want. I edited to add such examples above. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Working on my previous comment; this:

```
Sound[{SoundNote["D", 1, "Violin"], SoundNote["E", 1, "Violin"], 
  SoundNote["F", 1, "Violin"], SoundNote["G", 1, "Violin"], 
  SoundNote["A", 1, "Violin"], SoundNote["B", 1, "Violin"]}]
```

plays a succession of 6 notes for 1 second each. `Violin` specifies the instrument; there are a lot of different styles in the Details and Option in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SoundNote.html).

Comment: Unfortunately `SoundNote` has fixed frequencies, you cannot move away from halftone multiples; what I need is to have arbitrary frequencies